# Why the plot is not starting from zero in matplotlib and instead it starts from minimum value in the y entry

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I reading a file into pandas data frame (df_model_1) which contains probability of a,b,c,d,e.

```
df_model_1.to_csv("letters_prediction_file.csv", index=False)
values = pd.read_csv('letters_prediction_file.csv', header=0, sep=',')
x_letters = []
y_prob_value = []

for column in list(df_model_1):
        x_letters.append(column)
        y_prob_value.append(str(round(df_model_1[column].mean(), 4)))

pos = 10 
width = 0.10 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
Grph1 = np.arange(5)
LABELS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.xticks(x, LABELS)
plt.xlabel('TOP 5 Letters')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.bar(Grph1, y_prob_value, width, alpha=0.5, color='#EE3224', label='xyz') 
plt.savefig("ask.png")    
plt.show()
```

When I am plotting a bar chart, the min. value of y starts from 0.0909. I want y axis to start from 0 so that probabilty for D can also be shown in bar chart.

I have tried setting ylim=0  and bottom=0 , i could not understand why none of them works.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It does not start at `0.0909`. It starts at `0`. And `0` is labeled `"0.0909"`. As always: Do not use strings if you really want numbers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you so much.. It worked!!